# Не удаётся передать id в метод контроллера через ajax

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

Это элемент таблицы:

```
<tbody>
    @for (int i = 0; i < @Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr onclick="GetOrder('@Model[i].Id')">
            <th scope="row">@(i + 1)</th>
            <td>@Model[i].Number</td>
            <td>@Model[i].Date.ToString("d")</td>
            <td>@Model[i].ProviderName</td>
        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Функция js:

```
function GetOrder(id) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/Orders/GetOrder",
    type: "POST",
    data: { orderId: id }
});
```

В HTML генерится код: `<tr onclick="GetOrder('1')">` И в метод контроллера вызов проходит. Но в js параметр id всегда =0, data=null и в метод контроллера всегда приходит '0'. В другом проекте подобный код работал, но тот проект был на net5, а этот на net6, и это единственное отличие. В чём тут может быть дело?

Comment: data=null - не может быть равен null, если id=0 -> data: 0

Comment: Точка останова на $.ajax({ ?

Comment: Да ну, а в браузере ?

Comment: В самое начало функции `GetOrder` вставьте `alert("id="+id)`. Выводится?

Comment: В ajax написано  `type: "POST"`. Имелся в виду `method`? | Имя `GetOrder` метода контроллера подразумевает, что он обрабатываем http-method "GET". Разберитесь с этим.

Comment: alert("id="+id) - выводит правильное id

Comment: type: "POST", метод контроллера также имеет [HttpPost]

Comment: Покажите код методе контроллера. Сигнатуру и атрибуты.

Answer (score 0):

Дьявол кроется в мелочах)))
Контроллер ожидает параметр `int id`, соответственно `data: { orderId: id }` не верно. Нужно: `data: { id: id }`.
Весь код:

```
function GetOrder(id) {
$.ajax({
    url: "/Orders/GetOrder",
    type: "POST",
    data: { id: id },
});
```